# How to exclude `.git` then backup and restore folders and files owner and permission?

Tags: bash, acl

**I prefer to use bash script**,because `getfacl,setfacl` has big problem(bug).

Before I ask this question,I also search a way of pure `bash` script to backup and restore `owner and permission`.It's a pity that no one acknowledged perfect answer.

Then I use a easy way to backup and restore owner and permission:

```
getfacl -R . >permissions.facl
setfacl --restore=permissions.facl
```

If I want to exclude `.git` from `.`,how to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

For example, my directory looks like

```
[root@967dd7743677 test]# ls -la
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jan 11 06:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jan  2 11:08 ..
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Jan  2 12:56 .git
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 11 06:37 1one
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   19 Jan  2 12:55 testfile
[root@967dd7743677 test]#
```

by using `find` you can exclude any directory you want

```
find . -type f -not -path '*/\.git/*' -exec getfacl -R {} \;
```

so via `-exec` we are calling `getfacl -R`.

and you can redirect the output

```
find . -type f -not -path '*/\.git/*' -exec getfacl -R {} \; > permissions.facl
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Should add `-depth` in `find .`?

Comment: I want all folders and files,just exclude `.git`.I guess `-depth` doesn't matter the result.